# Pandas Date conversion time data '3-Oct-24 20:54' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M'

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Dataframe contains: "14-Jul-19" I am trying to convert this into date format in Pandas using

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
```

The column does not contains data in any other format nor empty values.

ERROR OCCURED:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vakakade\Anaconda3\envs\automations\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 456, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 350, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vakakade\OneDrive - Qualys, Inc\Work\Work_Code\vo-automation\src\windows_script.py", line 41, in fetchDetails
    df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
  File "C:\Users\vakakade\Anaconda3\envs\automations\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 801, in to_datetime
    cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
  File "C:\Users\vakakade\Anaconda3\envs\automations\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 178, in _maybe_cache
    cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, format)
  File "C:\Users\vakakade\Anaconda3\envs\automations\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 460, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\vakakade\Anaconda3\envs\automations\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 423, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    result, timezones = array_strptime(
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data '3-Oct-24' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y' (match)
```

Comment: use `format='%d-%b-%y'` - see [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) (or '%d-%b-%y %H:%M' for e.g. '3-Oct-24 20:54')

Comment: Does not work tried it.

Comment: Your pattern looks like it's looking for 0-padded dates, try %-d instead of %d to match the 3.

Comment: @mids: that's platform-specific; normally shouldn't be required.

Comment: @MrFuppes you are correct. Still I tried and no success

Comment: that's strange; `pd.to_datetime('3-Oct-24', format='%d-%b-%y')` works very well for me

Comment: @MrFuppes I am getting this data from a csv file where data is in same format at dataframe 3-Oct-24

Comment: Just omit the date formatting format='%d-%b-%Y' then it would be fine. Because it will be already formatted. If you insist you can provide the formatting as format='%d-%b-%y'

Comment: @LittinRajan that gives error dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Date

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the capital Y myself, a lowercase y is the one.

Answer (score -1):

Had to go with the workaround.
The solution

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%y %H:%M'))
```

Note: apply() does not have inplace had to reassign the column